# Expressing Euclidean isometries using complex variables

Tags: complex-numbers, euclidean-geometry, isometry, rigid-transformation

Studying for a final in my Euclidean geometry class and I'm having difficulties understanding how my book/professor explained Euclidean isometries.

He wants us to understand the classification of the rigid motions (translations, rotations, reflections, and glide-reflections) through their expressions using complex numbers.

I understand conceptually how these transformations work, but I'm not sure how to interpret them as complex functions. If someone could help me with this, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that multiplication by $i$ is a $90^\circ$ counterclockwise rotation?

Comment: Yes, it's more like, if I'm given an expression, how do I determine which of the following it is (i.e. what do their base expressions look like)

Comment: Maybe you should give us a few examples, since it's not clear yet what you're asking.

Comment: Look at mobius transformations , your transformations have the simplification that a= 1 or -1 and c= 0 , the complications that z can sometimes be conjugate (z)  but for the rest it is the same